# c printf signed float

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, signed

What is the formatter to make sure that + or - signs are always shown in front of the float value in printf() in C?
I haven't done C in a while, so where can I find a good reference on the web, any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put a `+` sign after the `%` but before the field width, the precision specifier, or the `f`. For example, use `"%+10.2f"` for a ten character wide field with two digits after the decimal.

From [printf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **+**
>
> A sign (+ or -) should always be placed before a number produced by a signed conversion. By default a sign is used only for negative numbers. A + overrides a space if both are used.

Comment: +1: but maybe add an example for clarity, e.g. `printf("x = %+g\n", x);` ?

Answer (score 2):

"%+f" is what you're looking for (though note that when you print it, you'll actually be printing a double, not a float -- a float is implicitly promoted to double when passed to a function that doesn't have a prototype or for a variadic argument).